# Line integral problem given two points and circle arc

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Given $A(-1,-2)$; $B(2,1)$  the arc $AB$ is from the following circle $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{9}{2}$. calculate $\int _T  \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}dx-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$ $T$ is the arc $AB$ from point $A$ to point $B$

I tried to solve this in a couple of ways but I don't know which one is right and why.

First was using potential since $P_y=Q_x$ , the potential is $\phi=arctan(\frac{x}{y})+c$ so I did $\phi(2,1)-\phi(-1,-2)$= $arctan(\frac{2}{1})$- $arctan(\frac{1}{2})$ but this seemed wrong for some reason..

The second thing was changed the line to going from point $A$  to a new point $D$ and then to point $B$ so it would be like that $(-1,-2)$ $\implies(2,-2)$ $\implies$ $(2,1)$ and $C:(t,-2)$ $C_1: (2,t)$

first integral : $\int_C \frac{-2}{t^2+4} \cdot1 -0 dt$ $=$ $-arctan(1)+arctan(\frac{-1}{2})$

Second integral : $\int_{C_1}0- \frac{2}{t^2+4} \cdot1 dt$ $=$ $-arctan(\frac{1}{2})+arctan(-1)$

Adding them I got : $-1.24-1.24=-2.48$

Third and last thing I tried was what the lecturer recommended and it was making a new equation that contains the two points and it would be $x^2+y^2=5$ because $||A||=||b||= \sqrt{5}$  but I could not complete it because I could not find $t_a \leq t \leq t_b$

[image]

thank you for any tips and help , and if the first way is not right then in which conditions can I use this?

Comment: Why do you think the potential answer is wrong? Clearly that's the potential function and so you used the fundamental theorem of line integrals.

Comment: @Triatticus because I got a different answer in the second way that I tried .. so I don't actually know which is wrong and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically on line integral from point $A (-1,-2)$ to point $B (2,1)$, yes you can evaluate it over the arc of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 5$ as the vector field is conservative in a domain that does not include origin.

$r(t) = (\sqrt5 \cos t, \sqrt5 \sin t)$

$t_A = - \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \arctan \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right), \ $
$t_B = \arctan \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$

$r'(t) = (- \sqrt5 \sin t, \sqrt5 \cos t)$

$\vec F (r(t)) = \left(\dfrac{\sin t}{\sqrt5}, - \dfrac{\cos t}{\sqrt5}\right)$

So the line integral is
$\displaystyle \int_{- (\pi/2) - \arctan (1/2)}^{\arctan(1/2)} - \ dt \approx - 2.4981$

On your first approach, please note that $- \arctan \left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$ has discontinuity at $x = 0$ (y-axis). It would work if we are restricted in the first and fourth quadrants.

Comment: as always thank you for the great help , can you please explain how you found $t_a$?

Comment: You are welcome. If $O$ is origin and $A$ is point $(-1,-2)$ then what is the angle that $OA$ makes with y-axis? If you draw a perp from $A$ to y-axis, you have a right angled triangle and $\tan \theta = \frac{1}{2}$. So that gives us angle of $-(\pi/2 + \theta)$ with positive x-axis. Is it clear?

Comment: yes ! thank you I totally forgot about that . much appreciated